# Singular/plural possessive form of fish?

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives

The singular form of *fish* is *fish*. The plural form of *fish* is also *fish*. What are their possessive forms?

Comment: Note that *fishes* is also a valid plural form (used in certain contexts) and is confusingly similar in pronunciation to the possessive *fish's*.

Comment: @TrevorD I believe that's for referring to groups of fish of different species.

Comment: @batpigandme So?

Comment: @Kris so, if you're wondering when to say fishes as opposed to fish now you know... I did many 'biodiversity' sample dives for marine biology, and when writing them up it certainly made a difference.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/586484/2085).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe) and the [Purdue OWL](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/621/01/) both note:

- Singular possessives always add *-’s.*
- Plural possessives add *-’s* if they don't already end in *s.*

Because the plural *fish* does not end in *s,* it becomes *fish’s,* just like the singular form.

**Note:** In some contexts, the plural of *fish* is *fishes.* Because that does end in *s,* it becomes *fishes’.*

Comment: What a gigantic pain English can be and I am a native speaker.

Comment: Except that it could as well be *fishes'*

Comment: Neither of the cited references says anything about *fish* or *fishes* -- or did I miss it?

Comment: I know. However, the statement "Therefore,..." is categorical and suggests no riders to "whether it is singular or plural."