# What are the fishes names?

Tags: grammar

There are some pet fish of the same species, which 'fish's is to be used when asking what their names are? Would it be:

- What are the **fish's** names?
- What are the **fishes'** names?
- What are the **fish** names?

Comment: Duplicate of closed question:  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114494/singular-plural-possessive-form-of-fish

Comment: The answer is fish's.  Fish is a singular and a plural. Therefore its possessive is also the same regardless.

Comment: All three are correct, depending on your use of the word, your stylistic use of the possessive, and how you choose to phrase the sentence.

Answer (score -1):

**Background:**

According to [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fish?s=t) plural of fish is *fish*.

This is correct if one is talking about a group or a *school* of fish of the same species.

However an aquarium filled with different species should be referred to as *fishes* as illustrated by [Woodward English](https://www.woodwardenglish.com/lesson/plural-of-fish-fish-or-fishes/):

[image]

**Answering the Question:**

Since the plural form of the same species of the fish remains *fish*. One would add an apostrophe to make it a singular possessives ie *’s* as indicated by [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe). Thereby it will be *fish's*

Therefore, from the three options you would say:

> What are the **fish's** names?

Comment: You didn't actually answer her question.  It wasn't about the pluralization, but rather the possessive for the plural of fish.

Comment: I improved it a bit..

Comment: Much better.  But, note that this question will likely be closed as the exact same question was closed in the past.  So, you might be downvoted by some users.  (Not my style)